# How to check if custom URL is +1'ed with Google Plus API?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

How can I check if user has +1'ed external page from my own page if I know his credentials?

Comment: Did you end up finding out how?

Comment: As far as I remember - no :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the current APIs.

There is, however, an [active feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=57&q=%2b1%27s&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary). If you star the issue, you will be notified when it is updated.