# How to know if the current user already +1 a specific link?

Tags: android, google-plus-one

Is it possible to know if the status of the plus one button? did the user already clicked this +1 button before? or is it possible to know if the user +1 a specific link?

I have a +1 button in my android application to let the user +1 my application thee one that he/she is currently using. What I want to do is to hide that button if the user already +1 my application, I only want to show the button for the user if he hadn't already +1 my app. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current google plus API, you can't know if a link was already plused.
Try to install a [listener on the plus button](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton.html#setOnPlusOneClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener%29) and on user +ing your app url save that value (when it is plused) so you don't show it again.

Note that you can't know if the same user plus it outside your app if it wasn't tracked.

There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761486/how-to-check-if-custom-url-is-1ed-with-google-plus-api) discussing this issue too